# Update the property of a array of object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react-redux.

Here I have an object which is like,

```
const initialState = {
Low: [
    {
        id: 0,
        technologyId: 0,
        technology: '',
        type: '',
        count: '',
        allowded: 6,
        level: 'EASY'
    }
],
Medium: [
    {
        id: 0,
        technologyId: 0,
        technology: '',
        type: '',
        count: '',
        allowded: 7,
        level: 'MEDIUM'
    }
],
High: [
    {
        id: 0,
        technologyId: 0,
        technology: '',
        type: '',
        count: '',
        allowded: 7,
        level: 'TOUGH'
    }
]
```

}

Now, this value is set it in the `reducer` I am taking it as a `props`.

Now, `onchnage` here the object property gets change from one of these obj.

So, Here the way I am updating it is ,

```
onChange(event, tobeupdated, id, type, noc, data) {
    let newData = { ...this.props.data };  
    if (newData) {
      let data = newData[type].map((object, index) => {
        if (object.id === id) {
          object[tobeupdated] = event.target.value;
      });
}
```

}

So,Here will I be updating the existing object  ?
Or is there any another way ?
What I tried was,

```
{...object, [tobeupdated]: event.target.value}
```

it is giving the compile time errors .
How can I resolve this ?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's what in the question above. Is `this.props.data` the `obj` you show at the top of the question? If so, why are you converting the array to an object with `{ ...this.props.data}`? Also note that the next line, `if (newData)` is pointless, because there's no chance that `newData` will be falsy. Later, you try to use `newData.map`, but `newData` is an object, not an array, and won't have `map`. There are also syntax errors in that code block that make it hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, actually I will update that array

Comment: Please check the question thanks sorry for that

Comment: Can you post your reducer on this question too ?